# Android studio mysql does not inserts into database code looks fine

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hello I am trying to add some value to my existing database table. Everything executes without errors, all variables are simple strings (checked). Maybe U can help me understand where the problem is here is the codes:

uzsisakyti click :

```
uzsisakyti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pastas",Global.elpastas ));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("slaptazodis",Global.slaptazodis ));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("naryste",trukme +" "+ "rad" +" "+ kaina.getText().toString()));
        HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                        + "Naryste.php");

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams() {
        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();    
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        return httpRequestParams;
    }
});
```

php file :

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("mysql10.000webhost.com","*","*","*");

    $pastas = $_POST["pastas"];
    $slaptazodis = $_POST["slaptazodis"]
    $nara = $_POST["naryste"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE User SET naryste='$nara' WHERE pastas='$pastas' AND slaptazodis= '$slaptazodis'");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Logcat :

```
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-02 17:05:04.350    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at com.tonikamitv.loginregister.Naryste$3.onClick(Naryste.java:86)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
06-02 17:05:04.360    9381-9381/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `"INSERT INTO User naryste VALUES nara WHERE pastas= $pastas AND slaptazodis= $slaptazodis"` missing brackets. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  <= use that for your query.

Comment: and I hope you'll change your DB credentials. Those look to be actuals.

Comment: however, INSERT does not have a WHERE clause, UPDATE does. Read up on INSERT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html and UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html - `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does have a WHERE clause http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html if that's what you meant to use. Plus, your variables are strings, quote them and your query needs brackets. Read up on the functions links I've provided.

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d. oh, and thanks for your sql credentials...

Comment: @MarcB only if it ever gets off the ground. and may not for a few reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO User naryste VALUES nara WHERE pastas= $pastas AND slaptazodis= $slaptazodis
```

is wrong

Correct syntax is `INSERT INTO User SET pastas="$pastas", slaptazodis="$slaptazodis", naryste="$naryste"` but it really depends on the table structure you are using.

Comment: you're partly right and partly wrong. Plus, OP's query is wrapped in double quotes, so this will fail since we're dealing with strings. OP may be wanting to do an UPDATE, who knows.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have update my question please take a look.

Comment: @ben I don't know anything about Android, sorry.

Comment: @Abby Chau Yu Hoi Hey I updated post please take a look